# Moment of inertia and centre of masses of continuous bodies

Tags: integration, moment-of-inertia, calculus, reference-frames

I'm quite accustomed with integration and all those calculus involved in finding moment of inertia as well as center of mass.
But a random thought is wiggling in my mind.
Why do we take $dm$ instead of $dr$ in finding moment of inertia and center of masses of continuous bodies?

Comment: Can you give some more context for where "dm" shows up, and why you would expect "dr" instead?

Comment: As you know, dm shows up when we're calculating the Moment of Inertia or Centre of Mass... Well, It's just a random thought of using dr. What if I integrate dr along the whole surface and get the same answer. That's what I 've asked

Comment: Off the top of my head I didn't know specifically what formula you were talking about.  Try to show in the question where $dm$ shows up and why you would like to replace it with $dr$ so that people don't already have to know the equation you're talking about to understand the question.

Comment: Related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/326637/understanding-the-differential-in-integrals/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moment of inertia: why $\mathrm{dI}=r^2\mathrm{dm}$ instead of $\mathrm{dI}=m\mathrm{dr^2}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411576/)

Comment: First define moment of inertia without using any differential calculus. Then convert your definition into an integral however you like. Same for centre of mass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that your $dm$ means
$$
\int_V r^2 dm = \int_V r^2 \rho(\vec{r}) dV
$$

And you might be thinking why it wouldn't look something like
$$
\int_0^r m(r) d(r^2) = \int_0^r m(r) 2r dr
$$

It's quite clear they are not the same, one is a 3 dimensional integral while the other is one. I suppose one could define a *"moment of inertial within distance r"* to make the second equation work out to the same answer but that would miss the point.

The point is, as with many physical quantities defined as an integral over a continuous space, to understand the quantity measured on an infinitesimal element first. For a very **small block** of mass $m$ **far away** at a distance r, the moment of inertial is defined as
$$
I=m r^2
$$
Now, we all know that an integral is nothing but a sum of many infinitesimal elements. **But what is it that is divided into many small elements?** Is it r? No, the block is far away and r is a large number! Is it m? Yes, because the block is very small! To turn the above equation into an infinitesimal element ready to be integrated, only one version make sense.
$$
dI=r^2 dm
$$
While the other version
$$
dI=m d(r^2)
$$
doesn't mean what you want to calculate. It's inconceivable as a small element and you don't know what it means to add it up.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant explanation!